# VBA: How to concatenate range of cells in a column with strings and generate it in another column?

Tags: vba, excel

I just can't work around this particular problem of mine where I have to concatenate all cells with data to a string, (e.g. " or ') in one column and then generate that concatenated result in another column.

Expected result:

```
Column A = ABCD
Column B = 'ABCD',
```

**My Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Concatenator ()

    Columns("B") = "'" & Range(Range("A1"), Range("A1").End(xlDown)) & "',"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

I would put the code in a **FOR Loop**:

```
Sub Concatenator()

Dim lastLng As Long

lastLng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row

    For x = 1 To lastLng

    Cells(x, 2).Value = "'" & Cells(x, 1).Value & "',"

    Next x

End Sub
```

Alternatively, if you don't want to use a loop, you can use the code below to paste your formula in column B:

```
Sub Concatenator()

Dim lastLng As Long

lastLng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row

    Range("B1:B" & lastLng).Formula = "=""'"" & A1 & "",'"""

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

or you could use this

```
Sub Concatenator()   
    Range("A1", Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues).Offset(, 1).Formula = "=concatenate(""'"",RC[-1],""'"")"    
End Sub
```

or this:

```
Sub Concatenator()
    With Range("A1", Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp))
        .Offset(, 1).Value = Application.Transpose(Split(Replace("'" & Join(Application.Transpose(.Value), "'|''") & "'", "'''", "''"), "|"))
    End With
End Sub
```